# Newbie in Java (handwritten notes: Implements vs Extends)

Tags: java

I just started learning Java and I've been reading, outlining, and taking notes from my book, "Murach's Java Programming (5th Edition)".

Despite my notes, I'm still getting confused in Java. I just want to know if I wrote my notes correctly? I did look online for assistance (including some posts in this forum), but I'm still not sure I did it right.

*(PS: I'm probably going to need more help with my notes. Should I re-use this thread, or create a new topic?)*

---

#### MY NOTES

The **implements** keyword is used for the following:

1. To inherit interfaces (technically “sub-interfaces”).
2. If you don’t want to inherit ALL methods and fields, then you must declare it as an abstract class.

The **extends** keyword is used for the following:

1. To create subclasses (as discussed earlier, in Chapter 8).
2. To inherit other classes (subclasses, children).

*Use this mnemonic: “you implement interfaces and extend classes”*

Comment: The notes about the implements keyword are both wrong or phrased weird: 1. What is a sub-interface supposed to be? 2. Declaring a class abstract has nothing to do with not wanting to "inherit all methods and fields". You always inherit everything when extend a class. 3. Also why do you suddenly talk about "abstract class" when this is supposed to be about interfaces and not classes?

Comment: *"1) To inherit interfaces (technically “sub-interfaces”)."*, no, when you *inherit* an interface, you do `extends`. `implements` is for *implementing* an interface.

Comment: *"2) If you don’t want to inherit ALL methods and fields, then you must declare it as an abstract class."*, you do that anyways when you inherit it.

Comment: *"1) To create subclasses (as discussed earlier, in Chapter 8)."*, yes.

Comment: *"2) To inherit other classes (subclasses, children)."*, yes.

Comment: "(PS: I'm probably going to need more help with my notes. Should I re-use this thread, or create a new topic?)" You should make a new question.  Limit your questions to *singular* questions.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: I got the part about abstract classes from here:

"When a class implements an interface it has to provide an implementation of all methods declared inside interface. **If It doesn't wish to provide all implementation, it can declare itself as an abstract class.**

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/difference-between-extends-and-implements-keywords-in-java.html#ixzz6NBs5uYeU"

Comment: @just_bri The bold part you posted is right, but says something completely different than what you written in your question.

Comment: If you create an abstract class that implements an interface, you do not have to provide the implementation of the interface methods yourself, but that abstract class will still have inherited everything from the interface.

Comment: @akuzminykh: Thank you for the help too!

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS: Okay that makes a bit more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example might get the concept across more clearly.

```java
class Car {
  public abstract String getMake();
  public abstract String getModel();
}
interface AlarmSystem {
  public void setPanicAlarm(boolean state);
}
```

Now you can create a class like this:

```java
class MyCar extends Car implements AlarmSystem {
  private boolean panic = false;
  public String getMake() { return "Ford"; }
  public String getModel() { return panic ? "Loud Mustang" : "Mustang" };
  public void setPanicAlarm(boolean state) { panic = state; }
}
```

You can say "MyCar is a Car".  The "IS A" concept is important. Using `extends` is the same as saying "IS A".  It does not make sense to say "MyCar is an AlarmSystem" though.  That's a "HAS A" relationship.  Saying "MyCar is a Car and has an AlarmSystem" makes sense.

When building classes ask yourself whether the class "IS" an instance of its superclass (the one it extends).

In the example you can imagine there are other Cars that do not have alarm systems and that's fine. Some don't.

So perhaps a better way to write your notes is:

**The implements keyword is used for the following:**

- To implement Interfaces to add capabilities to your class

**The extends keyword is used for the following:**

- To create subclasses of existing classes so you can extend and customize them while inheriting all of the capabilities of the parent class

Comment: This makes a LOT of sense using "is a" and "has it". I think I actually get it now; thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 0):

***1) To inherit interfaces (technically “sub-interfaces”).***

An Interface can extend one or more other interfaces. The term inheritance is not commonly applied to interfaces. Please mind that interface can have no methods and fields declared at all and serve just as a marker.

***2) If you don’t want to inherit ALL methods and fields, then you must declare it as an abstract class.***

An abstract class can have implementations for some methods, can have some nonpublic fields and methods, so it has a lot of differences compared to the interface.

I would suggest to see it form another point - Interface declares the protocol of communication in the first place - so it defines the methods which could be called regardless of implementation. An abstract class provides some implementation for some methods. If you are taking into account default methods in the interfaces - I would recommend you avoid them for starters - as they were added for specific purposes and pretty unlikely will be needed by you while you are learning.

***The extends keyword is used for the following:*
*1) To create subclasses (as discussed earlier, in Chapter 8).***

To create subclasses and to extend interfaces.

***2) To inherit other classes (subclasses, children).***

Not sure what is the difference for you with the previous point, as subclasses are created via inheritance using extends keyword. So I would merge this to statements.

Comment: It's starting to make more sense now. Thank you!